# Change color text in javascript

Tags: javascript, colors, passwords

I'm new in javascript and I want to change color for different classes in this code below. I want for example class 'ok' color green, class 'error' color red.

```
$('#pass').keyup(function (e) {
    var strongRegex = new RegExp("^(?=.{8,})(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\\W).*$", "g");
    var mediumRegex = new RegExp("^(?=.{7,})(((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]))|((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]))|((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]))).*$", "g");
    var enoughRegex = new RegExp("(?=.{6,}).*", "g");
    if (false == enoughRegex.test($(this).val())) {
        $('#passstrength').html('Minimum 6 znaków');
    } else if (strongRegex.test($(this).val())) {
        $('#passstrength').className = 'ok';
        $('#passstrength').html('Silne!');
    } else if (mediumRegex.test($(this).val())) {
        $('#passstrength').className = 'alert';
        $('#passstrength').html('Średnie!');
    } else {
        $('#passstrength').className = 'error';
        $('#passstrength').html('Słabe!');

    }
    return true;
});
```

Comment: `$('#passstrength').className` will not work. Use `addClass()` and `removeClass()`.

Comment: Just use `addClass()` .. defined your css already with the colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use proper jquery function to add the desired class .

```
$('#pass').keyup(function (e) {
    var strongRegex = new RegExp("^(?=.{8,})(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\\W).*$", "g");
    var mediumRegex = new RegExp("^(?=.{7,})(((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]))|((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]))|((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]))).*$", "g");
    var enoughRegex = new RegExp("(?=.{6,}).*", "g");
    if (false == enoughRegex.test($(this).val())) {
        $('#passstrength').html('Minimum 6 znaków');
    } else if (strongRegex.test($(this).val())) {
        $('#passstrength').addClass('ok');
        $('#passstrength').removeClass('alert');
        $('#passstrength').removeClass('error');
        $('#passstrength').html('Silne!');
    } else if (mediumRegex.test($(this).val())) {
        $('#passstrength').addClass('alert');
        $('#passstrength').removeClass('ok');
        $('#passstrength').removeClass('error');
        $('#passstrength').html('Średnie!');
    } else {
        $('#passstrength').addClass('error');
        $('#passstrength').removeClass('ok');
        $('#passstrength').removeClass('alert');
        $('#passstrength').html('Słabe!');

    }
    return true;
});
```

The `addClass` adds the specified class(es) to each element in the set of matched elements. So use that to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with this `$('#passstrength').className`

[className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) is native javascript method to set or return the class

where as `$('#passstrength')` is a jquery object, `className` will not work with this jquery object

But it will work with `document.getElementById('passstrength').className='yourClassName'`

and with jquery `addClass` & `removeClass` will work

Comment: ok thank you for yours response but now when I'm typing password color is changing and when I'm deleting letters colors stays from the last color. How can I change that?

Comment: @sirswistak what are you using javascript or jquery?

Comment: javascript. I add in css colors for each class and it works but when you delete password color stays

Comment: delete  means what?Share the updated snippet and specify which part is not working